Search and highlight a row in an Excel sheet which contains two or more different data
I want to query based on the values ​​in different cells in an Excel sheet and color the rows where these values ​​are located at the same time. The current code just colors a single line and the loop stops. Can you help me, where should I fix the code to apply the loop to the entire table?
Sub SearchAndHighlightIE()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim searchRange As Range
    Dim foundCell As Range
    Dim firstAddress As String
    Dim searchTerm As String

    ' Kullanicidan arama terimi al
    'searchTerm = InputBox("Aranacak kelimeyi giriniz:", "Arama Terimi")

    ' Eger kullanici bir sey girmeden iptal ederse, makroyu sonlandir
    'If searchTerm = "" Then Exit Sub

    ' Aktif çalisma sayfasini ayarla
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
  
    ' Arama yapilacak alan (tüm sayfa varsayilan olarak)
    Set searchRange = ws.UsedRange
  
    ' Arama terimiyle ilk bulusu bul
    Set foundCell0 = searchRange.Find(What:="Ýmal Edilen", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart)
    Set foundCell1 = searchRange.Find(What:="SLDPRT", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart)

    ' Eger bir sonuç bulunursa
    If Not foundCell0 Is Nothing Then
        firstAddress0 = foundCell0.Address
        
    If Not foundCell1 Is Nothing Then
        firstAddress1 = foundCell1.Address
        Do
        
            ' Hücreyi sariyla isaretle
            foundCell0.EntireRow.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 153)
            ' Sonraki bulusu ara
            Set foundCell0 = searchRange.FindNext(foundCell0)
        Loop While Not foundCell0 Is Nothing And foundCell0.Address <> firstAddress0
    
    Else
            
        MsgBox "Aranan terim bulunamadi."
    End If
    End If
End Sub



If the columns are fixed then you can use autofilter to achieve what you want. No need to loop. Please confirm the columns in which you want to search values?

OR for a non VBA solution, you can use conditional formatting...

I don't want to deal with autofilter. I would like to put an icon on a ribbon and by clicking on this to see the rows which includes two different data at the same time.

I think you misunderstood me... Autofilter is only to identify the rows which match your requirement Once the rows are indetified using autofilter, we will remove the autofilter and then color the row. It will be a quick process and the user will not see the autofilter.

Please confirm the columns in which you want to search values? If you can answer this then i can perhaps give you a demo?

Cloumns are fixed to be searched. Column 2 and 12. List will change day to day. So autofiltering is not an efficent way to see the both values in both columns. That's why I would like to use an icon in the ribbon to do so.

Yes you can use the icon from the ribbon. You do not need to click on autofilter manually. You may want to see how I have used Autofilter via VBA to move relevant rows to another sheet. In this link,I am only checking 1 column. Same logic can be applied to check for 2 columns...

No, this is not what I need...

First value is in the column 2, Second value is in the column 12, those columns are fixed and in the same row. VBA code should find first value then find second value and highlight entire row. That's it what I asked @siddharthrout

And that is what I answered. Let me give yo uan example.


First value is in the column 2, Second value is in the column 12,
those columns are fixed and in the same row. VBA code should find
first value then find second value and highlight entire row. That's it
what I asked siddharthrout – Gürkan Durukal  Commented1 hour ago

Based on the sample file given in the comments below, I have updated the post.
I have commented the code so you should not have a problem understanding it. Still if you do, then simply ask.
Option Explicit

Sub SearchAndHighlightIE()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim HighLightRange As Range
    Dim VisibleAreas As Areas
    Dim LastArea As Range
    
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim i As Long
    
    Dim FirstSearch As String
    Dim SecondSearch As String
    
    '~~> Change this to the relevant sheet
    Set ws = Sheet2 ' Sheets("1164A6")
    
    FirstSearch = "SLDPRT"
    SecondSearch = "Edilen"
    
    With ws
        '~~> Remove any filters
        .AutoFilterMode = False
        
        .Cells.Interior.Color = xlNone
        
        lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
       
        With .Range("A1:N" & lRow)
            '~~> Filter the data based on 1st column
            .AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="*" & FirstSearch & "*"
            '~~> Filter the data based on 2nd column. This way you
            '~~> will get rows which will have both search terms
            .AutoFilter Field:=12, Criteria1:="*" & SecondSearch & "*"
            
            '~~> This is the filtered range
            Set HighLightRange = .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow
            'Debug.Print HighLightRange.Address
        End With
        
        '~~> Remove any filters
        .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
    
    '~~> Check if filtering returned any range
    If Not HighLightRange Is Nothing Then
        '~~> Check if there are multiple areas
        If HighLightRange.Areas.Count > 1 Then
            Set VisibleAreas = HighLightRange.Areas
            '~~> Color the areas except the last empty one
            For i = 1 To VisibleAreas.Count - 1
                VisibleAreas(i).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 153)
            Next i
        Else
            '~~> Only one area was found, color it directly
            HighLightRange.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 153)
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox "Both terms not found in the same row"
    End If
End Sub

Output


Dear @siddharthrout,
I applied your code above but it gives only one coloured row at the end of the list only

I changed only those sections:
'Option Explicit
FirstSearch = "SLDPRT"
SecondSearch = "İmal Edilen"

.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="SLDPRT"
.AutoFilter Field:=12, Criteria1:="İmal Edilen"
Note: Sending a screenshot is not possible via this page :/

What happens when you try .AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="*" & FirstSearch  & "*" and .AutoFilter Field:=12, Criteria1:="*" & SecondSearch & "*"

It results syntax error :\
I removed "and" in the code and syntax error disappeared but gives nothing:
        .AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="*" & FirstSearch & "*"
        .AutoFilter Field:=12, Criteria1:="*" & SecondSearch & "*"


LOL. "and" is not part of the code. Those are 2 lines, put one below the other. Anyways, the code shold work. possible to see your file?

The code block is too long to share from here. Which way do you prefer for receiving a code block or file itself, an e-mail maybe?

You can upload the file on a free file sharing site and then update the above post with the link. Ensure that you remove any confidential informaiton before you upload.

https://baismakina-my.sharepoint.com/:x:/g/personal/gurkan_durukal_bais_com_tr/EazxvzNgSG9JopxNsphscfkBkLCWyQmy3MRk2NfzQf7j8w?e=K2UHS5

1. Which sheet are you testing this on? I believe 1164A6?  2. Also the text that you are searching for has special characters like İ which Excel can't recognise and hence then 2nd filter is failing. Instead of searching for "İmal Edilen", search just for "Edilen" 3. BTW you are searching for SLDPRT in the 2nd column. It should be the 3rd column. 4. I am updating the above post with the correct code. Let me know if it works now.

It works, thank you...
